# How to make a custom ListView for Parse.com

Tags: android, listview, parse-platform

I have a listview which displays the name of restaurants,based on my query, in my list view. However I want to be able to show more than just the name for each restaurant. I want to be able to show the location and rating for each item in my list view. This is my code so far

```
public class ResterauntList extends Activity {
    String cValue = null;
    String lValue = null;
    String rValue = null;
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_resteraunt_list);

        Bundle bdl = getIntent().getExtras();
        cValue = bdl.getString("cValue");
        lValue = bdl.getString("lValue");
        rValue = getIntent().getStringExtra("restrauntName");
        pickMethod();
    }

    @SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
    public void pickMethod() {
        if (cValue == null) {
            if (lValue == null) {
                populateList(rValue, "name");
            } else {
                populateList(lValue.toLowerCase(), "area");
            }
        } else {
            populateList(cValue, "cuisine");
        }
    }

    private void populateList(final String Value, final String Key) {
        ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<ParseObject> factory = new ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<ParseObject>() {

            @Override
            @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
            public ParseQuery create() {
                ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("resdb");
                query.whereEqualTo(Key, Value).addAscendingOrder("name");
                return query;
            }
        };
        ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject> adapter = new ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject>(
                this, factory);
        adapter.setTextKey("name");
        adapter.setTextKey("area");
        adapter.addOnQueryLoadListener(new OnQueryLoadListener<ParseObject>() {

            @Override
            public void onLoading() {
                mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(ResterauntList.this);
                mProgressDialog.setTitle(Value + " Restaurants Search");
                mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
                mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                mProgressDialog.show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoaded(List<ParseObject> objects, Exception e) {
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.restListView);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                ParseObject object = (ParseObject) listView
                        .getItemAtPosition(position);
                String Id = object.getObjectId();
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        SingleRestraunt.class);
                i.putExtra("restId", Id);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }
```

This is the xml file.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.gastronomaapp.ResterauntList" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/restListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:textSize="40sp" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Ive read a number of tutorials on customizing list views and understand a bit on how to do it in general but i cant seem to figure out where i should make changes in my code. Could somebody tell me how to go about this specifically for my above code?

Answer (score -1):

A good tutotial for begginers: http://hmkcode.com/android-custom-listview-items-row/

Just copy paste the row layout and see how the getView method goes...

Comment: Im finding it a little confusing when trying to figure out the change to be made to my current code. For example they all define their adapters as ArrayAdpater whereas mine is for parse. Could you be a little more specific?

Comment: once u parse the content you build an ArrayList. Same thing for "as you parse the content" you build an ArrayList. You just have a list and create the adapter.

Comment: The question is talking about Parse.com library.